# Why getattr is throwing 'module' object is not callable Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why I am getting error **'module' object is not callable** here

```
import platform

mm = ['architecture', 'collections', 'java_ver', 'libc_ver', 'mac_ver', 'machine', 'node', 'os', 'platform', 'processor', 'python_branch', 'python_build', 'python_compiler', 'python_implementation',
      'python_revision', 'python_version', 'python_version_tuple', 're', 'release', 'sys', 'system', 'system_alias', 'uname', 'uname_result', 'version', 'win32_edition', 'win32_is_iot', 'win32_ver']


for i in mm:
    c = getattr(platform,i)()
    print(c)
```

I am trying to call output like `platform.archirecture()` so have added parentheses

Comment: What's your (*.py*) script name?

Comment: its dum.py is this the reason ?

Comment: Well, one of the attributes you're trying to call is a module, not a function. Put a `print(i)` before the `getattr` line to see where it fails…

Comment: what did you name your file if its the same as the module you imported then rename it.

Comment: As the error states, not all are methods (or to generalize: *callable*s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `try-except` block to prevent this error.

```py
import platform

mm = ['architecture', 'collections', 'java_ver', 'libc_ver', 'mac_ver', 'machine', 'node', 'os', 'platform', 'processor', 'python_branch', 'python_build', 'python_compiler', 'python_implementation',
      'python_revision', 'python_version', 'python_version_tuple', 're', 'release', 'sys', 'system', 'system_alias', 'uname', 'uname_result', 'version', 'win32_edition', 'win32_is_iot', 'win32_ver']


for i in mm:
    try:
        c = getattr(platform,i)()
    except TypeError:
        c = getattr(platform,i)
    print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this – only call the callable members.

I removed some entries from the list since they weren't relevant, or can't be called without arguments.

```
import platform

mm = [
    "architecture",
    "collections",
    "java_ver",
    "libc_ver",
    "mac_ver",
    "machine",
    "node",
    "os",
    "platform",
    "processor",
    "python_branch",
    "python_build",
    "python_compiler",
    "python_implementation",
    "python_revision",
    "python_version",
    "python_version_tuple",
    "release",
    "system",
    "uname",
    "version",
    "win32_edition",
    "win32_is_iot",
    "win32_ver",
]

for name in mm:
    attr = getattr(platform, name, None)
    if not attr:
        continue
    if callable(attr):
        attr = attr()
    print(name, attr)
```

Comment: Thanks  may I know whats the use on None ?

Answer (score -1):

it also can be when you call the module object meaning the module's object have the same name as the module so try renaming at c = getattr(platform, ...)
change platform bc its the same name as the module. :)